# How to create a SharePoint Workflow in Visual Studio?

Tags: workflow, development, visual-studio

I would like to design a workflow in Visual Studio. The workflow consists of 4 approvers. The workflow should start when a new task is created in SharePoint list and it should send an email to both the creator and approvers.

How should I do it?

Comment: You asked about visual studio, but then tagged it SharePoint Designer? Which one is it? And, if it's VS, what let you to choose that? Also, what version of SP?

Comment: Thank you for responding.I want to use visual studio because it will give me more control on the workflow.My share Point is 2013.

Comment: Have you identified specific functionality that VS provides that SPD is incapable of? Most people that try to build SharePoint workflows in VS regret it, as it's quite difficult to ramp up on. (And, SP 2013 workflows don't allow code at all, even in VS, so while there are thing that are easier in VS, that list isn't all that long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the workflows in visual studio, as we know you can do this in SPD but someone sometime prefer the tool in which he is more comfortable, Workflows are created in one of three ways:

- Out-of-the-box SharePoint workflows that can be configured through a
  Web browser.
- SharePoint Designer workflows can be further customized with logic
  built-in.
- **Visual Studio workflows** have the most customizable features with more
  custom logic components.

This Youtube video has more details: [SharePoint 2013: Approval workflow using Visual Studio in SharePoint hosted app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jezCIhI7HZc)

See also:

- [Creating SharePoint 2013 Workflow Apps with Visual Studio](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/03/12/creating-sharepoint-2013-workflow-apps.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013: Approval workflow that uses a custom initiation form](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/SharePoint-2013-Approval-f5ac5eb2)